# OpenCPU: how to change the default port?

Tags: opencpu, rapache

Is there a way to have OpenCPU listening on a port different from `:80`?

It should be easy using Docker, but I'm running a dedicated Ubuntu machine as recommended [here](https://www.opencpu.org/download.html).

ps. I'm only using `opencpu-server` without `opencpu-cache` and so without nginx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It already runs on an additional port 8004 by default. You should be able to changed that in your `/etc/apache2/sites-available/opencpu.conf` file.

Comment: And how can I disable port `80`? I don't want to close it because I am exposing other contents through it, but I don't want OpenCPU to be accessible from that port.

Comment: Within opencpu.conf move the `/ocpu` handler into the 8004 virtual host and restart apache